# NSTextField with suggestions shown in dropdown

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am trying to implement autocomplete with an `NSTextField` where the user will type in some string and suggestions will be fetched from an API to be displayed under the text field. Optionally display a progress indicator inside the text field. So far I have designed the UI in Xcode IB and hooked the event to get the text change event.

```
    public class UserTextFieldDelegate: NSTextFieldDelegate
    {
        public NSTextField Username { get; set; }
        public UserTextFieldDelegate()
        {
        }
        public UserTextFieldDelegate(NSTextField username)
        {
            this.Username = username;
        }
        public override void Changed(NSNotification notification)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Username.StringValue);
        }
    }
```

The API will return a list of objects which I need to bind with the datasource of autocomplete list. 
[image: the required functionality sample]
How do I achieve this in Xamarin.Mac?

Answer (score 2):

In the `NSTextField.Changed`, save the `NSTextView` from the NSNotification parameter and call your Rest API:

```
NSString NSFieldEditor = new NSString("NSFieldEditor");
NSTextView editor;
[Export("controlTextDidChange:")]
public void Changed(NSNotification notification)
{
    editor = editor ?? notification.UserInfo.ObjectForKey(NSFieldEditor) as NSTextView;
    SomeRestCall(nsTextField.StringValue);
}
```

Now with your Rest method, call the actual Rest api via a background queue and  save/buffer the completion words returned in a string array and then call `NSTextView.Complete` on the NSTextView instance variable that you saved from the `Changed` method:

```
string[] completionWords = { };
void SomeRestCall(string search)
{
    if (editor != null)
    {
        DispatchQueue.GetGlobalQueue(DispatchQueuePriority.Background).DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
                completionWords = new string[] { };
            else
                // Fake a REST call...
                completionWords = (new string[] { "sushi", "stack", "over", "flow" })
                    .Where((word) => word.StartsWith(search, StringComparison.CurrentCulture)).ToArray();

            if (editor != null)
                DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() => { editor?.Complete(null); });
        });
    }
}
```

In your implementation of `INSTextFieldDelegate` add the `GetCompletions` protocol and return completion words that you saved in the last step:

```
[Export("control:textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:")]
public string[] GetCompletions(NSControl control, NSTextView textView, string[] words, NSRange charRange, ref nint index)
{
    requestor = null;
    return completionWords;
`}
```

Comment: I pressed "s" and suggestions dropdown opens, now I press backspace and it doesn't hides away.
Suggestions dropdown doesn't hides even if value is selected by hitting enter or mouse click unless space is pressed. 
I cannot get the key for values being displayed in the suggestions when an item is selected.
The suggestion dropdown doesn't covers the complete text field as in google search.
Is ComboBox the alternative?

Comment: @FaisalGhaffar That is just an example, not a full implementation. You would need to handle all the keyboard input to the field and act on it accordingly. By default the NSTextField word completions feature is just that, individual word completions. If you are looking for an individual char-by-char search field or suggestion field, you should look at NSSearchField/NSSearchFieldCell and dynamically display a TableView under it. Or look at the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` protocal, or subclass NSTextView and override methods like  `rangeForUserCompletion` to build your own custom views.

Comment: @FaisalGhaffar You could also use a `NSComboBox` and implement the `INSComboBoxDataSource` and `INSComboBoxDelegate` if that fits your use-case